# getEntity call results in crash (using odata4j on a WCF service)

Tags: android, wcf, odata, odata4j

I am trying out odata4j in my android app to retrieve data from a DB that can be accessed from a WCF service.

```
 ODataConsumer co = ODataConsumer.create("http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/Users");
 for(OEntity user : co.getEntities("Users").execute())
 {
      // do stuff
 }
```

However this crashes at the call to getEntities. I have tried a variety of other calls as well, such as

```
 Enumerable<OEntity> eo = co.getEntities("Users").execute();            
 OEntity users = eo.elementAt(0);
```

However this also crashes at eo.elementAt(0).

The logcat doesn't tell me anything, and the callstack seems to be Suspended at ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity.

Entering "http://localhost:xxxx/Users" in my web browser on the other hand works as expected and returns the users in my DB in xml format.

Any ideas on how I can debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the call should be:

```
ODataConsumer co = ODataConsumer.create("http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx");
for(OEntity user : co.getEntities("Users").execute())
{
     // do stuff
}
```

`create` defines service you want to connect but `Users` is the resource you want to query.

Comment: ah silly me - yes I had tried this initially. I have removed 'Users' from the call to create, however it still hangs at getEntities :(

Comment: Just first check - can your android application even access the address? Otherwise can you use something like Fiddler and compare request from browser and request from android?

Comment: yes if I use HttpGet instead, my Android can access the address. Unfortunately Fiddler doesn't show me any new items when I step over the getEntities loop.

Comment: Well just a silly try. What if you add trailing slash to the url?

Comment: tried adding trailing '/' to the url in the create method, unfortunately no luck still

Comment: Also what happens if you call just `co.getMetadata()`? Does it also hangs?

Comment: How many Users do you actually have in your database? What happens if you just try to retrieve single user?

Comment: I actually have 2 users at the moment. I attempt to get a single user using something like: 
      `OEntity user = co.getEntity("Users", "1eb11842-6f04-4de2-9524-05ed836e3fa3").execute();`

where the second parameter is the UserId, however this also crashes.

Comment: Unfortunately the logcat doesn't display any error, however looking at the Variables view, I see 'RuntimeException', 'Expected status 404 or 200 or 204, found 400:\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>\r\n<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">\r\n  <code></code>\r\n  <message xml:lang="en-US">Bad Request - Error in query syntax.</message>\r\n</error>'

Comment: Well we are back in need for fiddler (did you configure android application to use Fiddler as http proxy?). If you are not able to use fiddler, try [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) - check trace file and look for Process action activities and in the action for incoming HTTP request - it should contain url.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried configuring Fiddler but I still don't see anything from the android emulator.  I am trying WCF tracing, and I see  the http request that was made to http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/Users('1eb11842-6f04-4de2-9524-05ed836e3fa3'), and a few items later on I see 'Throwing an exception'. 'The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportReplyChannelAcceptor+TransportReplyChannel, cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted'.

Comment: You mentioned that service works from the browser so use it and check differences between android request processing and browser request processing.

Comment: oh right - yes I do see a difference, in both I see at least two "Active Boundary" items. However in the successful one, between the last two 'active boundary' messages I see 'Writing of a syndication item started. Writing of a syndication item completed. Sent message over a channel.' The failed one I don't see any of this, only 'From: Execute 'System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler.ProcessRequestForMessage'.

Comment: So the service fails immediately once it receives the request. Just in case - do you use any security / authentication - including authentication on web server?

Comment: You can also turn on passing exception details from the service to client - standard `includeExcpetionDetailInFaults` (if you are using WCF 4 just add it to default behavior).

Comment: I don't use any security\authentication at the moment, and unfortunately adding `includeExceptionDetailInFaults` in my config file only results in an error when i try to start the service: The type initializer for 'System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility' threw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

To log all http requests/responses:

```
ODataConsumer.dump.all(true);
```

The uri passed to the consumer .create call should be the service root. e.g. .create("http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/");  Otherwise your code looks fine.

Note the Enumerable behaves like the .net type - enumeration is deferred until access.  If you plan on indexing multiple times into the results, I'd suggest you call .toList() first.

Let me know what you find out.

Hope that helps,

 - john

Comment: thanks for your tip.  Where do all the http requests\responses get logged after ODataConsumer.dump.all(true)?

Yes I modified the url in my create method but it still crashes :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way.

```
OEntity oEntity;     
         OQueryRequest<OEntity>  oQueryRequest=  oDataJerseyConsumer.getEntities(entityName);
         List<OEntity>  list=  oQueryRequest.execute().toList();

         for (OEntity o : list) {
                List<OProperty<?>> props = o.getProperties();
                for (OProperty<?> prop : props) {
                    System.out.println(prop.getValue().toString());

                }

        }
```